# How can I remove lag on my image carousel?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to remove a lag on an image carousel on a personal website I have been working on.  I was able to make the carousel work fine, but the images are really laggy until I make my way all the way through the carousel of the photoalbum (you can see what I have [here](https://nickcosmo.com/)).  I have the code set up so that the image file locations are in an array and the src of the background image changes to a new location based on adding new text from the array.  Do you have a recommendation on how I can remove the lag?  I have tried a few things with the fetch api but I have only used this to fetch and parse json data so I am a bit confused on how to make it work on local files, but I assume I need to somehow make this asynchronous.  Any help or resources you can share is greatly appreciated!

The button cycles through like so:

```
let album = 2;
let currSlide = 0;
divContainer.style.backgroundImage = picArray[album][currSlide];

right.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(currSlide == picArray[album].length - 1){
        currSlide = 0;
        divContainer.style.backgroundImage = picArray[album][currSlide];
    }
    else {
        currSlide = currSlide + 1;
        divContainer.style.backgroundImage = picArray[album][currSlide];
    }
});
```

and the array looks like this:

```
let picArray = [
[   "url('Pictures/Amsterdam/1.jpg')",
    "url('Pictures/Amsterdam/2.jpg')",
    "url('Pictures/Amsterdam/3.jpg')",
    "url('Pictures/Amsterdam/4.jpg')",
    "url('Pictures/Amsterdam/5.jpg')",
    "url('Pictures/Amsterdam/6.jpg')",
    "url('Pictures/Amsterdam/7.jpg')",
    "url('Pictures/Amsterdam/8.jpg')",
    "url('Pictures/Amsterdam/9.jpg')"
],
[   "url('Pictures/OregonCoast/1.jpg')",
    "url('Pictures/OregonCoast/2.jpg')",
    "url('Pictures/OregonCoast/3.jpg')",
    "url('Pictures/OregonCoast/4.jpg')"
]
```

Comment: Have you tried compressing your images? Maybe your images are too big for it to load faster. Also check where you're hosting the images, that could also be a problem at times. You can also checkout Lazy Loading for images. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images are too long, so it take time to load.

1. One way to improve. Load image before ur carousel started. Use `show hide` to toggle.
2. Pre cache images using the network.
3. Use a small image for display in thumbnail.

**See the sample below.**

```js
let album = 2;
let currSlide = 0;
const divContainer = document.getElementById("images");

const right = document.getElementById("rightB");

let picArray = [
  "https://nickcosmo.com/Pictures/RoseGarden/1.jpg",
  "https://nickcosmo.com/Pictures/RoseGarden/2.jpg",
  "https://nickcosmo.com/Pictures/RoseGarden/3.jpg",
  "https://nickcosmo.com/Pictures/RoseGarden/4.jpg",
];
divContainer.innerHTML = picArray.map((src) => `<img src="${src}" />`).join("");
const images = divContainer.querySelectorAll("img");
let index = 0;
images[index].classList.add("active");
right.addEventListener("click", () => {
  images.forEach((img) => img.classList.remove("active"));
  images[index++].classList.add("active");
});
```

```css
#images img {
        display: none;
      }
      #images .active {
        display: block !important;
      }
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
    <button class="moveB" id="leftB">‹</button>
    <button class="moveB" id="rightB">›</button>
    <div id="images">
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for sharing this!  I made something fairly similar that is working now, appreciate the help!